# How to add a margin to a datetime picker component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Two date pickers positioned side by side. I am trying to give `marginRight` after 1st date picker.

// app.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import DateTimePicker from "@mui/lab/DateTimePicker";

export default function BasicDateTimePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date());

  return (
    <div>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DateTimePicker
          renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
          label="DateTimePicker"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          sx={{ '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
            mr:5
          } }}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DateTimePicker
          renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
          label="DateTimePicker"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

how to add a margin or padding after a date picker?
`sx={{ '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': { mr:5 } }}`

is showing no effect.

codesandbox url for this code is https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-morning-jzhkd?file=/src/App.js:0-1120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your margin on the `TextField` you're feeding to `renderInput`

```
        <DateTimePicker
          renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} sx={{ mr: 2 }} />}
          label="DateTimePicker"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
        />
```

Comment: This is ok but there's a typo: when it says "sx={{ mr: 2 }}" it should say "sx={{ m: 2 }}". Change mr for m.

Comment: Why is that a typo?  They were asking for margin right and that is what supplies it  https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/

Comment: @possum, Can we change the same style with a styled component? but won't work.. I want change input style

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo with the sx params, it should be:

```
<DateTimePicker
  renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} sx={{ m: 2 }} />}
  label="DateTimePicker"
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
/>
```